# how to make div use 100% of available height?

Tags: html, css

I have next html:

```
<div class="left">
    <div style="margin: 32px 0;">
        <div class="border"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
.left {
    position:absolute;
    background: red;
    height: 50%;
    width: 32px;
}
.border {
    background: green;
    height: 100%;
}
```

but I don't see green box :(

UPD: I want to see red squares over and under green box.
UPD2: height of green box should be red.height - 32px*2

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you have 3 empty div's here and not one of them has a set height. So even if you do `min-height: 100%` its not going to work unless some outer container has a height that your not showing. You will need to put some content in there or give one of the 3 div's (assuming they are the only containers on the page) an actual height. Like `.left{ height: #px; }` (# = the height you want it to have). Otherwise the browser does not know how to render percentages because it has nothing to relate them too.

Div's are block level elements which means they will assume the size of content put in them but *if there is no content in them they will assume a height of 0px by 0px.*

http://jsfiddle.net/X6qkL/5/ updated

Comment: added &nbsp; http://jsfiddle.net/X6qkL/2/ i can't set height of left fixed, because it should  use all available space

Answer (score 2):

The second div is not assigned a height, so the innermost div cannot be assigned a relative height.  Try adding the following CSS rule:

```
.left div {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Or, assign explicit heights to the inner divs.

http://jsfiddle.net/B9z92/1/

Comment: @andrew you have a margin top on it of 32px so it is going to show some red.

Comment: I don't see red square at bottom

Answer (score 0):

Use `min-height: 100%;` in `.border{...}`. and add a class 
    `.middle {
        height: 100%;
    }` and assign it to the parent `div` of `.border{...}` div.

Comment: green box moved out from red one :(